# Android image file is corrupted

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am producing thumbnails of the images to show in a list.
I have this piece of code:

```
SoftReference<Bitmap> mThumb;
mThumb = new SoftReference<Bitmap>(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), options));
```

When an image file which is corrupted comes in the process. It throws an exception. How to handle this.

Comment: can use some placeholder image for such cases inside catch block

Comment: what do you mean by corrupted?  file does not exist or not image ?

Comment: say I created a text file in phone and added .png extension in the name. So it is not a image file but the program sees it as image. When try to open in the gallery it is corrupted.

Comment: `the program sees it as image`. Which program? Im shure BitmapFactory will not. So i see noproblem.

Comment: @greenapps The program that I am developing. It looks at the extension of the file. So it sees it as a png file. So it starts to make a thumbnail then it gives the error